# Missing gcov symbols with mingw under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc, mingw32

Before upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 I could compile the following code with mingw-64-gcc

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -fprofile-generate -o test.exe test.c -lgcov -static

```
//test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{puts("test");return 0;}
```

Now the program cannot be linked due to missing __gcov symbols.

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -fprofile-generate -o test test.c
/tmp/cccj8pnx.o:test.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call_profiler_v2'
/tmp/cccj8pnx.o:test.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `__gcov_time_profiler'
/tmp/cccj8pnx.o:test.c:(.data+0xa0): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_time_profile'
/tmp/cccj8pnx.o:test.c:(.rdata$.refptr.__gcov_indirect_call_callee[.refptr.__gcov_indirect_call_callee]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gcov_indirect_call_callee'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What has changed between between the two Ubuntu versions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, and I was able to work around it by linking to `-fprofile-arcs` rather than `-lgcov`.

Comment: This does indeed make the link succeed, but running doesn't produce any .gcda files and is thus useless.   I noticed that `libgcov.a` is practically empty (still, on Ubuntu 19.10).   Can't find any trace what changed and why.